# Display APEX logs in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, force.com, apex

I just installed the Force.com IDE in Eclipse Kepler.

My code:

```
public with sharing class Test {
    public Test() {
        system.debug('ssss##########################################');
    }
}
```

I go in 'Execute Anonymous' and type:

Test t = new Test();

The output:

> Anonymous execution was successful.
>
> 29.0
>   APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;VALIDATION,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
>   Execute Anonymous: Test t = new Test();
>
> 15:09:35.033 (33141000)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>
> 15:09:35.033 (33163000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
>
> 15:09:35.033 (33887000)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmB9Z.png)|()
>
> 15:09:35.033 (33955000)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmB9Z.png)|()
>
> 15:09:35.209 (34026000)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
>
> 15:09:35.209|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
>
> Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
>
> Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
>
> Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
>
> Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
>
> Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
>
> Number of code statements: 0 out of 200000
>
> Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
>
> Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
>
> Number of callouts: 0 out of 10
>
> Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
>
> Number of fields describes: 0 out of 100
>
> Number of record type describes: 0 out of 100
>
> Number of child relationships describes: 0 out of 100
>
> Number of picklist describes: 0 out of 100
>
> Number of future calls: 0 out of 10
>
> 15:09:35.209|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
>
> 15:09:35.034 (34080000)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
>
> 15:09:35.034 (34094000)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

No debug logs displayed, and I set up the console as follow:

[image: Screenshot Eclipse]

I am very new in APEX.
Many thanks

F

Answer (score 1):

Change Picklist Log category: "Apex Code"  in Execute Anonymous Tab, To max level.